# Why kafka consumer don't use jdk InterruptedException when poll()?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, interrupted-exception

I have noticed that [KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) advocates to use `wakeup()` and custom boolean to close KafkaConsumer:

```
 public class KafkaConsumerRunner implements Runnable {
     private final AtomicBoolean closed = new AtomicBoolean(false);
     private final KafkaConsumer consumer;

     public KafkaConsumerRunner(KafkaConsumer consumer) {
       this.consumer = consumer;
     }

     public void run() {
         try {
             consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("topic"));
             while (!closed.get()) {
                 ConsumerRecords records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10000));
                 // Handle new records
             }
         } catch (WakeupException e) {
             // Ignore exception if closing
             if (!closed.get()) throw e;
         } finally {
             consumer.close();
         }
     }

     // Shutdown hook which can be called from a separate thread
     public void shutdown() {
         closed.set(true);
         consumer.wakeup();
     }
 }
```

Why don't KafkaConsumer `poll()` method throws jdk InterruptedException, then we can just handle InterruptedException, thus avoid to write shutdown method using these two steps:

```
         closed.set(true);
         consumer.wakeup();
```

Kafka explains that:

> Note that while it is possible to use thread interrupts instead of wakeup() to abort a blocking operation (in which case, InterruptException will be raised), we discourage their use since they may cause a clean shutdown of the consumer to be aborted. Interrupts are mainly supported for those cases where using wakeup() is impossible, e.g. when a consumer thread is managed by code that is unaware of the Kafka client.

But indeed I'm not so aware of its meaning. Can anyone explain it more explicitly?

Besides, `poll()` throws `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException`, which is an unchecked wrapper for jdk InterruptedException. Why bother using this new exception?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I am facing a problem too where sometime on consumer.poll() i am getting the org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException. Not sure what is causing it.